# Multiplication table with special format using Python

Tags: python

I did the following python code which is multiplication table with special format:

```
print('| *  |', end='')
for col in range(10):
    print(' %02i' % col, end=' |')
print()

print('--------------------------------------------------------')

for row in range(10):
     print('| %02i |' % row)

print()


for row1 in range(10):
    print("%02i"%row1, end=' | ')
    for col1 in range(10):
        print("%02i" %(row1*col1), end=' | ')
    print()
print()
```

So the output is

[image]

but I need the output like the following pic:

[image]

Comment: if you are willing to use a 3rd party library, i suggest you use https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate .

Comment: Your code is merly functional. Hint 1: some lines need to be removed. Hint é: change a little just one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first row `for` loop so that the code becomes:

```
print('| *  |', end='')
for col in range(10):
    print(' %02i' % col, end=' |')
print()
print('--------------------------------------------------------')
for row1 in range(10):
    print('|',"%02i"%row1, end=' | ')
    for col1 in range(10):
        print("%02i" %(row1*col1), end=' | ')
    print()
print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your outcome is logical because you first print the beginning of every row with

```
for row in range(10):
     print('| %02i |' % row)

print()
```

And then the results with

```
for row1 in range(10):
    print("%02i"%row1, end=' | ')
    for col1 in range(10):
        print("%02i" %(row1*col1), end=' | ')
    print()
print()
```

You can combine the two to give the results you want, just paste the innercode of the second loop inside the first loop, under the `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Can do this:

```
print('| *  |', end='')
for col in range(10):
    print(' %02i' % col, end=' |')
print()
print('--------------------------------------------------------')
for row in range(10):
     print(('| %02i |' % row)+' | '.join(['%02i' % (i*row) for i in range(10)]))

print()
```

Already do the calculations while creating the rows.

Output:

```
| *  | 00 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09 |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 00 |00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00
| 01 |00 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09
| 02 |00 | 02 | 04 | 06 | 08 | 10 | 12 | 14 | 16 | 18
| 03 |00 | 03 | 06 | 09 | 12 | 15 | 18 | 21 | 24 | 27
| 04 |00 | 04 | 08 | 12 | 16 | 20 | 24 | 28 | 32 | 36
| 05 |00 | 05 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 | 30 | 35 | 40 | 45
| 06 |00 | 06 | 12 | 18 | 24 | 30 | 36 | 42 | 48 | 54
| 07 |00 | 07 | 14 | 21 | 28 | 35 | 42 | 49 | 56 | 63
| 08 |00 | 08 | 16 | 24 | 32 | 40 | 48 | 56 | 64 | 72
| 09 |00 | 09 | 18 | 27 | 36 | 45 | 54 | 63 | 72 | 81
```